# How to carry out MySQL query involving join of two tables

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join

I have two tables in a database.

First table is `books` having fields *number*,*title*,*subject area*, *author*. 
Other table is `borrowed_items` having fields *item_number* , *user_id* , *issue date* and *return date* .

How to carry out query to find book title whose subject area is 'Physics' and are borrowed i.e. exist in borrowed items table ?

The 'item_number' field in borrowed_items table corresponds to 'number' field in 'books' table.

Comment: You certainly tried something, could you show it ?

Comment: RTFM http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/es/join.html

Comment: I dont know the sql command which involves two tables. After googling I got some clue. 
I tried following:
SELECT S.Title FROM (select Item_Number from borrowed_items ) as S where S.Subject_area='Novel'

Comment: But the above command is not working and I know the reason. Not getting any other way so asked here.

Comment: You should also look at your database relations. `item_number` in one table and `number` in another isn't good practice. It makes more sense for the column names to match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  a.*, b.*       -- you can select your desired columns here
FROM    books a
        INNER JOIN borrowed_items b
            ON a.`number` = b.item_number
WHERE   a.`subject area` = 'Physics'
```

To further learn more about joins, please visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins)

Comment: +1 for the reference to explain joins as well as posting the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT books.title 
FROM   books JOIN borrowed_items ON borrowed_items.item_number = books.number
WHERE  books.`subject area` = 'Physics'
```